# Eclipse: Java, see where class is used

Tags: java, eclipse, search

Is there a way in Eclipse to select a Java class, and then bring up a list of all Java files where that class is used within a project?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

right-click on the class, and select references/Project

For searching all of the workspace, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

Answer (score 26):

Put the cursor on the class name (works for methods, constructors, fields, etc, too), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Since Eclipse 4.12 you can also use the code minings feature:

[Eclipse minings settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6UeN.png)