# Method of finding all the classes used by a main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I am provided with a workspace where i have to extract few classes. I know the main classes which have to be extracted. Is there a way in eclipse which lists all the classes used by this main class. Indirect and direct references of this class.

For example:
I have main class A which uses class B and class C. Class C internally uses class D.
So for all the classes used in A should list B,C and D.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse: Java, see where class is used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504784/eclipse-java-see-where-class-is-used)

Comment: @NicoVanBelle The OP seems to be asking the direct opposite this: the list of all classes that *this class* refers to, directly *or indirectly*. You've shown how to get the list of classes that are referring *to* this class (directly only)

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the classes folder of your application and compile only the class you want to obtain dependencies for using [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)  where you provide the classpath of dependent jars (if any). The java compiler will find all the dependencies of this class and compile them as well:

```
javac -classpath dep1.jar;dep2.jar path.to.your.class.YourClass.java
```

Comment: So then you find the result by looking in the target directory for the compilation?

Comment: You can create a job that lists the output of the classes directory after you compile, or even make a shell or batch file that wraps the whole process

Comment: Thanks. But this solution might be tricky because my application is spread across module.

Comment: You can give it a try and adapt it to suite your case